# Finding substring, but not for all inputs?

Tags: c, arrays, string, substring

I wrote a code to find the index of the largest substring in a larger string.

A substring is found when there is an equal amount of `a`'s and `b`'s.

For example, giving `12` and `bbbbabaababb` should give `2 9`, since the first appearing substring starts at index 0 and ends at index 9. `3 10` is also an answer, but since this is not the first appearing substring, this will not be the answer.

The code I made is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

void substr(char str[], int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    int max = -1, start;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (str[i]=='a') {
            str[i] = 0;
        } else if(str[i]=='b') {
            str[i] = 1;
        }
    }

    // starting point i
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        sum = (str[i] == 0) ? -1 : 1;

        // all subarrays from i
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            (str[j] == 0) ? (sum += -1) : (sum += 1);

            // sum == 0
            if (sum == 0 && max < j - i + 1 && n%2==0) {
                max = j - i + 1;
                start = i-1;
            } else if (sum == 0 && max < j - i + 1 && n%2!=0) {
                max = j - i + 1;
                start = i;
            }
        }
    }

    // no subarray
    if (max == -1) {
        printf("No such subarray\n");
    } else {
        printf("%d %d\n", start, (start + max - 1));
    }
}


/* driver code */
int main(int argc, char* v[]) {
    int n;              // stores the length of the input
    int i = 0;          // used as counter

    scanf("%d", &n);

    n += 1;         // deals with the /0 at the end of a str

    char str[n];    // stores the total

    /* adding new numbers */
    while(i < n) {
        char new;
        scanf("%c", &new);
        str[i] = new;
        ++i;
    }

    substr(str, n);

    return 0;
}
```

It works for a lot of values, but not for the second example (given below). It should output `2 9` but gives `3 10`. This is a valid substring, but not the first one...

Example inputs and outputs should be:

```
Input      Input           Input
5          12              5
baababb    bbbbabaababb    bbbbb
Output     Output          Output
0 5        2 9             No such subarray
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: (Note: Instead of modifying `n` in `n += 1`, you should adjust the dimension of the array: `char str[n + 1]` and explicitly add the `'\0'` at the end. The string should be null terminated, but `str[n]` is not really part of the string data.)

Comment: @Bram Koop I have not understood how you are determining a substring.

Comment: Yes, the explanation is sketchy: The string consists only of `a` and `b`. A valid substring has the same number of `a`s and `b`s. (This should be part of the question.)

Comment: What happens if you initialise `int start = 0;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems, many of them to do with arrays sizes and indices.

- When you read in the array, you want `n` characters. You then increase `n` in oder to accomodate the null terminator. It is a good idea to null-terminate the string, but the `'\0'` at the end is really not part of the string data. Instead, adjust the array size when you create the array and place the null terminator explicitly:

  ```
  char str[n + 1];

  // scan n characters
  str[n] = '\0';
  ```
- In C (and other languages), ranges are defined by an inclusive lower bound, but by an exclusive upper bound: `[lo, hi)`. The upper bound `hi` is not part of the range and there are `hi - lo` elements in the range. (Arrays with `n` elements are a special case, where the valid range is `[0, n)`.) You should embrace rather than fight this convention. If your output should be different, amend the output, not the representation in your program.

  (And notw how your first example, where you are supposed to have a string of five characters actually reads and considers the `b` in the 6th position. That's a clear error.)
- The position of the maximum valid substring does not depend on whether the overall string length is odd or even!
- The first pass, where you convert all "a"s and "b"s to 0's and 1's is unnecessary and it destroys the original string. That's not a big problem here, but keep that in mind.

The actual problem is how you try to find the substrings. Your idea to add 1 for an "a" and subtract one for a "b" is good, but you don't keep your sums correctly. For each possible starting point `i`, you scan the rest of the string and look for a zero sum. That will only work, if you reset the sum to zero for each `i`.

```
void substr(char str[], int n)
{
    int max = 0;
    int start = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i + max < n; i++) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
            sum += (str[j] == 'a') ? -1 : 1;

            if (sum == 0 && max < j - i) {
                max = j - i;
                start = i;
            }
        }
    }

    if (max == 0) {
        printf("No such subarray\n");
    } else {
        printf("%d %d\n", start, start + max);
    }
}
```

Why initialize `max = 0` instead of `-1`? Because you add +1/−1 as first thing, your check can never find a substring of `max == 0`, but there's a possibility of optimization: If you have already found a long substring, there's no need to look at the "tail" of your string: The loop condition `i + max < n` will cut the search short.

(There's another reason: Usually, sizes and indices are represented by unsigned types, e.g. `size_t`. If you use `0` as initial value, your code will work for unsigned types.)

The algorithm isn't the most efficient for large arrays, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks! I will update and try my code as soon as possible! Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: I updated my question. My code now works for more values, but not for the second example. It should give `2 9`, but gives `3 10`.

Comment: Please don't modify the question with substantial changes. My answer has now lost its context.

Comment: But to answer your question: The code works when I declare the array directly like so: `char str[] = "bbbbabaababb";`. Your problem is how you scan the input: The first character is neither `'a'` nor `'b'`, but the newline after the length. You could fix this by only counting a's and b's as valid input or by "eating" preceding whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines) with the ´" %c"`format. (Note the leading space.).

Comment: The empty space before ` %c` doesn't work. (If it should, I'm doing something wrong). But adding an if-statement around `str[i]=new;`, doesn't help much either. I tried: `if(new == 'a' || new == 'b'){` and `if(new != ' ') {`      _(I also put my old code back into the question, to give back the context of your answer)_

Comment: Thanks for rolling back the edits. When I look at the code that you changed accotrding to my suggestions, I see that you still have the `n += 1` in it. Remove that. Then `scanf(" %c", &new);` with a leading space or `if (new == 'a' || new == 'b') str[i] = new;` or both. With these changes, I get the correct answer. (If you want to analyze, separate the input from the algorithm and print out the contents of `str` to test it or, better yet, look at the value of `str` in a debugger.)

Comment: Oh! Of course! I forgot about the `n += 1`. I will try it asap

Comment: Thanks again for your help @MOehm! My code works now!